# How can you get new costumes in Resident Evil 4?

Tags: ps3, resident-evil-4-2005

I have seen them in action but I have no idea how to get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to finish the game once to unlock the first set of costumes. The second set is awarded by finishing the Separate Ways scenario.

Comment: Very interesting, because I think there is another costume available. You start off with a jacket (brown, leather) but later in the game you change into a gray shirt with leather suspender/knife holster.

Comment: That's the regular costume. You just lose the leather jacket during the game

Comment: I understand, but how do you lose the jacket, K3nel?

Comment: Actually as soon as you reach the end of Chapter 1-1. Well, it was the case on the PS2 and first PC version that I played.

Comment: I mean how. Not when. Do you lose it when unconscious? How?

Comment: It gets stolen by a villager. You see the jacket when you play the separate ways scenario